# Apply class to dynamically-placed rectangle

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

Is it possible to apply a class to rectangles that are dynamically made using jQuery?

I'm making a grid pattern with boxes of fixed dimension, to fill a page on load.

I wish to give each  its own class so I can style them in my CSS file.

Here's the relevant code.

```
var spacesWidth = Math.floor($(window).width() / 40);
var spacesHeight = Math.floor($(window).height() / 40);
for (i = 0; i < spacesHeight; i++){
    for (j = 0; j < spacesWidth; j++){
        var box = $(document.createElementNS("http://www.w3.org/2000/svg", "rect")).attr({
            width: 40,
            height: 40,
            x: j * 40,
            y: i * 40
        });
        $('#canvas').append(box);
        $('#canvas svg:last-child').attr("class","redDirt")
    }
}
```

I'm aiming to style each  depending on what class it has.

This will be used to randomly generate a grid terrain for a 2d strategy game.

How can this be done?

Comment: `$('#canvas svg:last-child').attr("class","redDirt")` not setting `class` `redDirt` at last `svg` ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If interpret Question correctly , try adding `class` at call to `.attr()`

```
  var box = $(document.createElementNS("http://www.w3.org/2000/svg", "rect"))
           .attr({
            // note, property "class" in quotes
              "class":"className",
              width: 40,
              height: 40,
              x: j * 40,
              y: i * 40
           });
```